# How to import multiple keras models into the same py file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

i am a beginner programmer, and I need to import 3 pre-trained keras models on the same file, then going with them to make a prediction and "printing" the image with opencv.
i am using python 3.8.5

```
#reset-50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

#vgg-16
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

#inceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import glob
import PIL
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def main():
   menu()


def menu():
    print("**************************")
    print()

    choice = input("""
                      A: Predict with RESET-50
                      S: Predict with VGG-16
                      D: Predict with Inception-V3
                      Q: Quit

                      Please enter your choice: """)

    if choice == "A" or choice =="a":
        reset50()
    elif choice == "S" or choice =="s":
        vgg16()
    elif choice == "D" or choice =="d":
        InceptionV3()
    elif choice=="Q" or choice=="q":
        print("Uscita")
        sys.exit
    else:
        print("You must only select either A or B")
        print("Please try again")
        menu()

def reset50():

    model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

    print("RESET-50")

    dir_path = os.chdir("xxx")
    count = 0

    #recupero tutti i file dalla cartella sopra con estensione JPEG ordinati per nome
    for i in (sorted(glob.glob('*.JPEG'))):
        img_path = i
        
        #carico tutte le immagini dalla cartella e ridimenziono 224x224
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))

        #converto immagine in array di pixel 
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

        #preparo l'immagine per il modello reset50
        x = preprocess_input(x)

        #prevedo la probabilità in tutte le classi di output
        preds = model.predict(x)

        #converto le probabilità in etichette di classe
        label = decode_predictions(preds)

        #recupero il risultato piu' probabile tra le etichette
        label = label[0][0]
        
        #stampo la classificazione
        print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2]*100))
        
        plt.imshow(image.load_img(img_path))
        plt.show()

        if(label[2]*100 > 55):
            count+=1
            
        
    print(count)
    
def vgg16():

    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

    print("VGG-16")

    #apertura directory
    dir_path = os.chdir("xxx")
    #inizalizzazione contatore
    count = 0
    #recupero tutti i file con estensione JPEG ordinati per nome
    for i in (sorted(glob.glob('*.JPEG'))):
        count+=1
        img_path = i
        
        #carico tutte le immagini dalla cartella e ridimenziono 224x224
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        
        #converto immagine in array di pixel 
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        
        #preparo l'immagine per il modello vgg19
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        
        #prevedo la probabilità in tutte le classi di output
        preds = model.predict(x)
        
        #converto le probabilità in etichette di classe
        label = decode_predictions(preds)
        
        #recupero il risultato piu' probabile tra le etichette
        label = label[0][0]
        
        #stampo la classificazione
        print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2]*100))
        
        plt.imshow(image.load_img(img_path))
        plt.show()
        
        if(label[2]*100 > 55):
            count+=1
    
    print(count)

def InceptionV3():

    input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

    model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

    print("Inception-V3")

    dir_path = os.chdir("xxx")
    count = 0

    #recupero tutti i file dalla cartella sopra con estensione JPEG ordinati per nome
    for i in (sorted(glob.glob('*.JPEG'))):
        img_path = i

        #carico tutte le immagini dalla cartella e ridimenziono 224x224
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))

        #converto immagine in array di pixel 
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)

        #preparo l'immagine per il modello InceptionV3
        x = preprocess_input(x)

        #prevedo la della classe di output
        preds = model.predict(x)

        #converto le probabilità in etichette di classe
        label = decode_predictions(preds)

        #recupero il risultato piu' probabile tra le etichette
        label = label[0][0]
        
        #stampo la classificazione
        print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2]*100))
        #print(decode_predictions(preds, top = 3))
        
        plt.imshow(image.load_img(img_path))
        plt.show()

        if(label[2]*100 > 55):
            count+=1

    print(count)
            

main()
```

going to run this code I report this error: **AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tensorflow.python.distribute.values' has no attribute 'DistributedVariable' (most likely due to a circular import)** how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO! Could you provide a stacktrace to your error?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509832/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-conf) answer your query?