# tensorflow (up to date, installed, but it doesn't get imported)

Tags: tensorflow

I don't think I am using an old version of tensorflow as :

```
pip show tensorflow

Name: tensorflow

Version: 2.5.0
```

When I try to run my code, for example:

```
median_income = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("median_income")
```

This error pops up:

```
 Exception has occurred: AttributeError
 partially initialized module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'feature_column' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I only have tensorflow (I don't have tensorflow-gpu)

Comment: Since you are not using GPU try using tensorflow-cpu instead (pip install tensorflow-cpu), see if it solves the issue. Uninstall all other versions of TensorFlow first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509832/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-conf)

Comment: It works fine in `Google Colab`. So, the error might be related to the problem mentioned in **Lescurel's** comment. Please let us know if the link mentioned in the above comment resolves your issue. Thanks!